# Why do I keep getting 0 when dividing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting, sum

I have the following piece of code that always results in 0.00. I know for sure that the weight_score is an actual number. Can someone help me format it so that it results in a decimal number. Using SQL server 2008 and this code is in a view. Thanks a lot!

```
CAST(SUM(weight_score * (45/100)) as decimal(10,2)) As avg_score
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

45/100 is implicitly treated as an INT divided by another INT, which results in an INT that gets rounded to 0. Add a decimal to each to work around that.

```
CAST(SUM(weight_score * (45.0/100.0)) as decimal(10,2)) As avg_score
```

Comment: @dido: Glad to help. Please remember to accept this answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
 45/100 is treated as INT.So change it to 45.0/100.0. 
 select CAST(SUM(weight_score * (45.0/100.0)) as decimal(10,2)) As avg_score

 Even if you write the following code you will get 0
 select (45/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the error, you can use the NULLIF function.